# Do Nested Transactions commit?

Tags: transaction, database-theory, database-agnostic, savepoint

I am not happy with the [Wikipedia article about nested transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_transaction).

I would not use the word "commit" for a nested transaction.

For me "commit" means "durability". A nested transaction does not provide durability.

1. Is it ok to use the word "commit" for nested transactions?
2. What word could be used, if it is not ok?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name according to wikipedia savepoints are a way to implement nested transactions. I thought postgres supports nested transactions since it supports savepoints: "A savepoint is a way of implementing subtransactions (also known as nested transactions) within a relational database management system by indicating a point within a transaction that can be "rolled back to" without affecting any work done in the transaction before the savepoint was created."

Comment: To me a savepoint is something (completely) different than a nested transaction, but that might just be me.

Comment: Commit means much more than durability, which isn't even a requirement in its usual sense (think pure in-memory databases). Transactions are about atomicity and isolation/visibility of changes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a problem using the word `commit` and personally I don't see a better wording for the concept.

Most database systems do not support nested transactions, the only one I could find is BerkelyDB.

In their [documentation on nested transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg_txn/JAVA/nestedtxn.html) they are using commit as the term.

> Committing a nested transaction has no effect on the state of the
>   parent transaction.

In the book [Concepts and Applications of Multilevel Transactions and Open Nested Transactions (1992)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.17.7962)  they seem to be using the same wording.

> subtransactions can be made persistent independently of their commit
>   state

Answer (score 4):

> Is it ok to use the word "commit" for nested transactions?

I think so. The syntax is still `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or `COMMIT WORK`. How 'commits' of nested transactions are handled is implementation-dependent, but it seems common to treat them as a no-op. Handling nested rollbacks is much more interesting. [In SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx) at least, it requires marking a savepoint to rollback to, if the intention is to undo only the locally-scoped work.

> What word could be used, if it is not ok?

It's probably simpler just to use 'commit', adding a note or clarification about the ACID properties where the context demands it.